# How do I convert a Matlab matrix to a python array

Tags: python, matlab

I have a 100x200 input, and a 1x100 target matrix that I am using to run a gridsearch and create a classifier in python. However, I get errors that my training set of target data is not an array. I've tried:

```
target=np.asarray(matTarget)
```

Where the matTarget is just my target imported from Matlab using scipy.io.loadmat.

My exact error is

```
len() of unsized object
```

When I try target.size I get a blank size as well.

If I do not do the array conversion, then I get

```
Expected array-like (array or non string sequence) got {'_header_': b'Matlab matfile ... Array([[1],[1]...)}
```

I still have the original matrix in Matlab and have also tried using np.array instead of asarray.

If I do `print(matTarget.keys())` then I get ('*header*`,'*version*','*globals*','y_train'])

y_train is the name of the mat file itself

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of [`scipy.io.loadmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) it returns a dictionary where the values are the contained matrices.

> **Returns:** mat_dict : dict
>
> dictionary with variable names as keys, and loaded matrices as values.

So you need to select your matrix by its name before using it with numpy:

```
matrix = matTarget['name of matrix']
```

Comment: So in your line there, is matrix the same as 'name of matrix'? So the matrix that I've imported from Matlab used the scipy.io.loadmat is called matTarget. The matrix that I'm trying to create is just target. So if I write the code according to your line there I get 'target=matTarget['target']' but how does that work if target is being defined as something of itself?

Comment: @aksharagarwal No, `'name of matrix'` is a string literal which you should replace with the actual name of the matrix in your Matlab file. `matrix` is a variable which stores a reference to the matrix returned by `matTarget[...]`. `matTarget` is a dictionary which contains the matrices' names as keys and the matrices themselves as values. Can you post the output of `print(matTarget.keys())` (maybe as an extension to your question)?

Comment: I added that output to the question. So should I run 'target2=matTarget('y_train') and then define target as np.asarray(target2)? Doing that gets me the error that dict is not callable

Comment: @aksharagarwal Yes but you need to replace the parentheses `( )` with square brackets `[ ]` because you want to `__getitem__` rather than `__call__` the dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed that and ran it with the brackets. Also, I just wanted to thank you for helping me out thus far. I took another look at the documentation for the import, and there is a 'struct_as_record' option so that would load the Matlab struct as a numpy record array. Would that work also?

Comment: @aksharagarwal I suggest not to modify this value, it seems to exist for backward compatibility reasons. Doesn't it work with the default values?

Comment: I got a different error this time (I didn't use the struct thing) that says "too many indices for array". I'm not quite sure what this means

Comment: @aksharagarwal Without posting the code which caused this error and the traceback it's hard to say what went wrong. But in general this means that the dimension of your indices exceeds the dimension of your array.

Comment: Sorry. So I tried following some other answers online, but even if I define my target and input matrices (like [1:500,:]) for both so that they have the same dimensions I still get the error. I am not there atm but I will post the code soon